# How to access a file system folder in Grails

Tags: grails

I uploaded some documents into an `uploadFolder` C:/upload config path

```
environments {
    development {
        uploadFolder = "C:/upload/"
    }
    production {
        uploadFolder = "C:/upload/"

    }
    test {
        uploadFolder = "C:/Users/"
    }
}
```

and I store it in the controller

```
documentInstance.fullPath = grailsApplication.config.uploadFolder + documentInstance.filename
```

How do I access the documents in the C:/upload/ file in Grails ?

Comment: and the problem is....?

Comment: How do I access the documents in the C:/upload/ file in Grails ? @injecteer

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference in how you access files in Grails then how you do it in a normal web application. If your paths are absolute paths you can do like this

```
def path = grailsApplication.config.uploadFolder + documentInstance.filename
File file = new File(path)
```

or to list all the documents in upload folder

```
Folder dir = new File(grailsApplication.config.uploadFolder)
dir.eachFile() {File file ->  doSomething..}
```